Customize order and punctuation in biblatex
it's my third day of fighting biblatex already. I'm writting my thesis from economics and have some strict editting requirements. I did my best to match the required citation scheme and after hundreds of copy-pasted codes from the Internet still haven't found the right solution. The biblatex documentation also isn't helpful for me - it's quite huge and too generic. My intention is to reorder the elements of the citations and change several dots to commas (as per images below). I'll be thankfull for working code, and/or some explanations. Note, that the gierszewska2017 is a book written by two authors. The kozminski2013 is a book written by multiple authors (not mentioned in citation) with two editors.
For book with authors I have:

G. Gierszewska, M. Romanowska. Analiza strategiczna
przedsiebiorstwa. Warszawa: Polskie Wydawnictwo Ekonomiczne, 2017, s.
26.

(authors. title. address: publisher, year, pages)
this should be (note commas):

G. Gierszewska, M. Romanowska, Analiza strategiczna
przedsiebiorstwa, Polskie Wydawnictwo Ekonomiczne, Warszawa 2017, s.
26.

(authors, title, publisher, address year, pages)
For book with editors I have:

A. Koźmiński, W. Piotrowski, red. Zarządzanie. Teoria i praktyka.
Warszawa: Wydawnictwo Naukowe PWN, 2013, s. 33.

(editors, red.. title. address: publisher, year, pages)
this should be (note commas):

Zarządzanie. Teoria i praktyka, praca zbiorowa pod red. A. Koźmiński, W. Piotrowski, Wydawnictwo Naukowe PWN, Wydanie V
zmieniona, Warszawa 2013, s. 33.

(title, praca zbiorowa pod red. editors, publisher, address year, pages)
Here is my MWE (I've added comments to clarify what I already achieved):
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[
citestyle=verbose-trad2,% Full bib entry in footcite + ibidem + opcit.
bibstyle=verbose,
ibidpage=true,          % Skip pages for the same footcite
pagetracker=false,      % Use Ibidem for all (even if source footcite is on the previous page)
giveninits=true,        % Use initials instead of full name
sorting=nyt,            % Sort bibliography by name, year, title
]{biblatex}             % Advanced control over bibliography
\DefineBibliographyStrings{polish}{%
    ibidem = {Ibidem},                      % Replace "Tamże" (Polish term) with "Ibidem"
    opcit = {op\adddotspace cit\adddot},    % Format op. cit. as required
    editor = {praca zbiorowa pod red.},     % Replace "red." with the required text
    editors = {praca zbiorowa pod red.}     % Replace "red." with the required text
}
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph}      % Italics Ibidem and op. cit.
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}   % Remove comma between the family and initials
% Separator between authors
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space} % comma space between consecutive authors
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space} % comma space for last author
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % Family goes before initials

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Lorem\footcite[26]{gierszewska2017} ipsum\footcite[25]{gierszewska2017} lorem\footcite[33]{kozminski2013}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}

My bibliography.bib contents:
@book{kozminski2013,
  editor    = {Andrzej Koźmiński and Włodzimierz Piotrowski},
  title     = {Zarządzanie. Teoria i praktyka},
  publisher = {Wydawnictwo Naukowe PWN},
  address   = {Warszawa},
  year      = {2013}
}

@book{gierszewska2017,
  author    = {Grażyna Gierszewska and Maria Romanowska},
  title     = {Analiza strategiczna przedsiębiorstwa},
  publisher = {Polskie Wydawnictwo Ekonomiczne},
  address   = {Warszawa},
  year      = {2017}
}

The current outcome:

The desired form:


Please ask only about one specific issue per question. That makes your questions easier to answer and more relevant for other people with similar problems. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864

For the position of the editor it looks like the option useeditor=false, could help. It can be applied globally or per-entry (via options = {useeditor=false,}, in the .bib entry).

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} will turn most full stops/period into commas. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864. This may or may not be what you want, though, since it applies to both the bibliography and citations and most punctuation (also for other entry types that weren't mentioned in the question).

@moewe thank you for your comments. I finally acomplished my requirements by manipulating the entries by hand using \renewbibmacro*{cite}(...) for footnotes and \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}(...) for bibliography. Unfortunately my university defined its own custom bibliography styling which was very hard to achieve in a fancy biblatex way...
